# jquery date picker disabling field

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

i have a situation that the jquery date picker is disabling my date field, for some reason.

here it is on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFEMA/

reproduce: choose a DAY.

then choose the MONTH for the same date set.

you will see that the day has been disabled completely for some reason. it should disable only the options that are not relevant for that month (eg: 29,30 and 31 for Feb).

any ideas why?

I am sure this was working at some stage...
thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using dropdowns to select month/day/year, when the entire purpose of the Datepicker is to eliminate such things? Just use a textfield. -- http://jsfiddle.net/VFEMA/3/

Comment: basically, because i am dealing with customers from all over the world - and i want it to be crystal clear, even with a glance, what the correct days are and not to have to work out dd/mm or mm/dd.

Comment: Then use the "dateFormat" option to make it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/VFEMA/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function

```
function checkLinkedDays2() {}
```

update the line

```
$('#x_StartDateD option').attr('disabled', '');
```

to

```
$('#x_StartDateD option').removeProp('disabled');
```

BTW: Why do you use the datepicker plugin if you're creating your own solution?

Comment: Thanks Thorsten - works great. only kink is that it seems to cut off an extra day. EG: for February, it will only give you 27 days, or 28 in a leap year.
and the reason i am using the plugin - is just to make this easier for folks - some might want to use the drop downs, some will wan the plugin. i found this solution somewhere and it seems to bridge them all.

Comment: For that extra day, just update the next line to $('#x_StartDateD option:gt(' + (daysInMonth) + ')').attr('disabled', 'disabled');